# 2 sets of numbers, a mix of numbers and letters, and 2 possible ciphers

Tags: cipher

This was created by a discord user called VOXEL in a server called Acro's Cave.
I'm on the 2nd to last step of this extremely irritating puzzle and I need some help.
I found a google document with the following text:

4459123
14580035
dv1y1y4ITPbib3
(<--- 10 -> 16)
y = (mx + b) % 26

I'm pretty confused on what to do with any of this, any help would be appreciated.

(NEW FIND) I just found out by guessing that if you use the keys a=5 and b=12 on dv1y1y4ITPbib3 using an online affine decoder, you get 'th1s1s4URLdud3'.
[image: shows the formula used and the output] What does this possibly cross off the list of the 5 clues I have to solve it? And what could I do with this and is it useful or is it nothing?

Comment: This puzzle was created by someone in a puzzle discord server I am in. I've been solving the entire thing for a bit over a week. I've basically been guessing on what to do for this exact step. The only progress I made was when I got the dv1y1y4ITPbib3 part using another piece of text in the document. I'm sure I have everything in the document so this is all I have now. This is my first time coming across this site, is there anything else I should know?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Yes, please take a look at our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259/81979).